# Wordpress warnings

Tags: php, wordpress, header, foreach, warnings

I am working on a ngo PROJECT. I prepared some stuff on my localhost and now uploaded to our test server. But when I try to open wp-admin of my wordpress, I get following warnings.

```
 Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/zooliepd/public_html/clients/sparsha/wp-includes/post.php on line 3589

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/zooliepd/public_html/clients/sparsha/wp-includes/post.php:3589) in /home/zooliepd/public_html/clients/sparsha/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 876
```

In my website I made posts page to my home page.

I tried to put ob_start(): in my header file but it didn't work! and no spaces are there in post file at given line number.

Plz help me

Comment: the second warning occurs due the first warning. Show us `wp-includes/post.php` line 3589 and the code arround it.

Comment: Try `ob_start();` on top of your function.php file if dosen't work try to upload the warning files again.

Comment: I've had this issue and it was caused by a plugin not being coded correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/zooliepd/public_html/clients/sparsha/wp-includes/post.php on line 3589
```

It is because `foreach` expects a array there, do like below :

```
if(is_array($your_arry)){
   foreach(){....}
}
```

put your `foreach` inside this condition

If first warning is fixed the second will go automatically, because second one caused because of first. :D

Comment: Thanks.. warnings are removed but home page is coming on the place of admin login page..

Comment: i putted foreach in this condition. if(is_array($page->ancestors)){...}